# Using SQL sequences

Tags: sql-server, spring, azure-sql-database, sequence, liquibase

How can I put sql sequences like the one below into liquibase changelog file (xml)?
Is it even possible?

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_option_1
START WITH COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM entity WHERE source = 'source1'), 1);
```

I don't have option to create a table with max ids.

I think I have to write this in T-SQL, so is there someone who knows Transact-SQL and could convert this sequence somehow with similiar result?

Comment: Why do you need to create a sequence that starts at the value of an existing ID? This smells like a possible [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

There's a [createSequence](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-sequence.html) change in Liquibase. But it looks like `startValue` only accepts integer values, and there are no attrubutes like `startValueComputed` as other changes have.

So in your case you may use plain `<sql>` change, e.g.:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <sequenceExists sequenceName="sequence_option_1"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <sql>
        CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_option_1 
        START WITH COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM entity WHERE source = 'source1'), 1);
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: It throws liquibase.exception.DatabaseException. Is it db fault? I'm using mssql and azure db

Comment: Is there any stacktrace? or root cause?

Comment: It  says: Exception encountered during context initialization... Error creating bean with name 'liquibase'... Migrattion failed for changeset... And then that the reasion is incorrect syntax near the word 'COALESCE'

Comment: I tried different ways but there is always error because of syntax

Comment: So it means syntax of your sql request is wrong. Fix it and you should be good. It's not a liquibase issue

Comment: Yeah but it is 100% correct. It is copied from test scope. Then liquibase was introduced and it throws exception

Comment: This is not valid SQL Syntax https://dbfiddle.uk/jlLF94h9 - the grammar expects `START WITH <constant>` not `START WITH` any random SQL expression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax

Comment: How could I make this working? I'm trying to do this with start value as a max id in table. It already took me a few hours and no success

Comment: You might be able to use dynamic sql to build the sequence from a non-constant expr